# why don't we multiply $\pi$ to integral to find volume created by cross section?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, area, volume

**Let's say that we are given the following image**

[image]

which $r(x)=2\sqrt{x}$

and we want to know the volume of the solid whose cross section taken perpendicular to the y-axis is a rectangle whose height is 3 times the length of its base in region R. I want to find an integral expression that gives the volume of the solid

**The question-**

According to my class, I would naturally have $\int_{0}^{6}\frac{3}{16}{y^4}dy$

I understand to do this, but why do we not square this and why do we not multiply by $\pi$?

Comment: Not at all understand, exactly what you are calculating

Comment: @KingTut i italicized what we are trying to find I already put in what we are trying to find

Comment: Um, why *would* you square it or multiple by $\pi$?

Comment: Multiplying by $\pi$ in these situations is most often done with [solids of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution). I don't see such a thing here, and thus I wouldn't expect $\pi$ to appear. How to set up an integral like this is entirely dependent on how the solid is created. If there is no rotation and no circles, then I see no reason $\pi$ should appear.

Comment: @fleablood coz I thought u would do dat in order to find volumes n' stuff?

Comment: @Arthur but isn't the rectangle created a solid that we are rotating?

Comment: The cross section of *what* solid?

Comment: @fleablood I italicized what we are trying to rotate, it's a rectangle with the dimensions given in the problem

Comment: Volumes of *what* stuff?  You really have not in anyway intiecated what you are trying to do.  Are you engaging in the "If it moves, salute it.  If it doesn't move, pick it up.  If you can't pick it up, paint it" school of thought of doing calculus because... I don't know *what* the eff you are trying to do.

Comment: @fleablood The description of the solid wasn't perfect, but it was, in my opinion, possible to decode. I have edited it to be a bit clearer. Does that help?

Comment: @bof u don't need the rectangle to solve it, I also just wanted to know why u don't need the pi and stuff thanks!

Comment: Okay,  You don't multiply it be $\pi$ because you are not ratating anything.  Because the cross section is rectangle the solid is just a tube like excrusion of this shape.  So you multiply by the length.  The lenght is 18.

Comment: "rectangle cross-section" = prism.  No rotation.

Comment: @fleablood lol wot I thought we create a rectangle and rotate it?

Comment: @fleablood Isn't a prism supposed to have constant height?

Comment: Cross-sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis are rectangles of area $A(y)=\left(3\frac{y^2}4\right)\left(\frac{y^2}4\right)$ and the area is $\int_{y=0}^{y=6}A(y)dy.$

Comment: It does have a constant height. or length.  It's on its side.  It's 18 inches long.  6 inches high.  and nine inches wide at the top and pin point at the bottom.  It's basically a bookshelf.   It's all the points $0 \le x \le 9$.  $2\sqrt x \le y \le 6$. and $0 \le z \le 18$.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYAru.jpg

Comment: Oh yes as bof says, i think height varies- " height is 3 times the length of its base in region R"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an image of the volume of interest, drawn to scale:

[image]

The cross sections comprising the intersection of planes perpendicular to the $y$-axis are rectangles, whose base is the horizontal distance between the $y$-axis and the curve $x = y^2/4$, and whose height is $3$ times the base.

In light of this diagram, the question becomes, why would $\pi$ be involved in such a volume calculation, any more than it would be involved in calculating the volume of a cube?  There are no circular cross sections.  Mathematics is about using deductive reasoning, logic, and rigor.  It is not about arbitrary choices or blind adherence to formulas.  Intuition can be motivation, but is never a sufficient foundation for proof.

To perform the requisite computation, it suffices to consider the differential volume of a representative rectangular cross section.  Since we already know that for a cross section corresponding to a particular $y$-coordinate $y_0$ has base of width $y_0^2/4$ and height $3(y_0^2/4)$, it follows that such a cross section would have differential volume $$dV = \frac{3}{4} y^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} y^2 \cdot dy = \frac{3}{16} y^4 \, dy,$$ 
as a function of a general $y \in [0, 6]$.  Consequently, the total volume is now found by integrating with respect to $y$ on this interval:  $$V = \int_{y=0}^6 \frac{3}{16} y^4 \, dy,$$ and the rest is straightforward.

Had the cross-sections been specified as, say, **semicircles** whose diameters are the horizontal distances from the $y$-axis to the curve $x = y^2/4$--that is to say, instead of rectangles, we used semicircular cross sections--then indeed we could see $\pi$ entering into the volume calculation, as the differential volume would then be $dV = \pi (y/2)^2/4 \, dy$.  But no such cross-section was given.

Comment: Oh... *That's* what "height = 3 times the base meant"!.